# How to plot a Plotly Isosurface with non-analytic data?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm taking some data from a weather model and trying to plot it as an isosurface inside of Plotly, but I'm getting a blank graph each time without any error messages. I'm new to plotly so this seems likely to be a simple issue. The documentation and tutorial pages were of no help.

I've reduced my input data to 3x3x3 3D arrays (that are flattened before sending to go.Isosurface), the data in 3D form is:

```
z_subset_tiled_2 = np.array([[[151.11943054, 151.11943054, 151.11943054],
        [151.11943054, 151.11943054, 151.11943054],
        [151.11943054, 151.11943054, 151.11943054]],

       [[255.65301514, 255.65301514, 255.65301514],
        [255.65301514, 255.65301514, 255.65301514],
        [255.65301514, 255.65301514, 255.65301514]],

       [[363.32260132, 363.32260132, 363.32260132],
        [363.32260132, 363.32260132, 363.32260132],
        [363.32260132, 363.32260132, 363.32260132]]], dtype='float32')

lat_subset_tiled_2 = np.array([[[14.10366  , 14.103652 , 14.103641 ],
        [14.112637 , 14.112626 , 14.1126175],
        [14.121613 , 14.121605 , 14.121593 ]],

       [[14.10366  , 14.103652 , 14.103641 ],
        [14.112637 , 14.112626 , 14.1126175],
        [14.121613 , 14.121605 , 14.121593 ]],

       [[14.10366  , 14.103652 , 14.103641 ],
        [14.112637 , 14.112626 , 14.1126175],
        [14.121613 , 14.121605 , 14.121593 ]]], dtype='float32')

lon_subset_tiled_2 = np.array([[[120.31331 , 120.32256 , 120.33182 ],
        [120.31332 , 120.32256 , 120.331825],
        [120.31332 , 120.32258 , 120.33184 ]],

       [[120.31331 , 120.32256 , 120.33182 ],
        [120.31332 , 120.32256 , 120.331825],
        [120.31332 , 120.32258 , 120.33184 ]],

       [[120.31331 , 120.32256 , 120.33182 ],
        [120.31332 , 120.32256 , 120.331825],
        [120.31332 , 120.32258 , 120.33184 ]]], dtype='float32')

theta_2 = np.array([[[301.3794 , 301.44308, 301.4732 ],
        [301.33685, 301.39835, 301.44403],
        [301.3008 , 301.35147, 301.40442]],

       [[301.39117, 301.46188, 301.48926],
        [301.34885, 301.41992, 301.46976],
        [301.31003, 301.37192, 301.43362]],

       [[301.49753, 301.57315, 301.5888 ],
        [301.4737 , 301.54742, 301.59207],
        [301.45   , 301.51346, 301.57153]]], dtype='float32')
```

and the plotting function is:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig= go.Figure(data=go.Isosurface(
    x=lon_subset_tiled_2.flatten(),
    y=lat_subset_tiled_2.flatten(),
    z=z_subset_tiled_2.flatten(),
    value=theta_2.flatten(),
    isomin = 301.4, 
    isomax = 301.5, 
    caps=dict(x_show=False, y_show=False)
))

fig.show()
```

The output that I get is:
[image: Blank Plotly 3D graph]

It doesn't even seem to pick up on the coordinates, so I'm hoping that there is something obvious that I'm wrong about here. The documentation to do stuff with real data is just not there though.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert with Plotly, but it seems that you cannot create an isosurface with points that are not ordered properly (i.e. a collection of points that form a surface but then also include more points interior to that surface)

For example, notice that while the following code renders properly:

```
fig= go.Figure(data=go.Isosurface(
    x=np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]),
    y=np.array([1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]),
    z=np.array([1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]),
    value=theta_2[0].flatten(),
    isomin = 301.3, 
    isomax = 301.6
))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Swapping the first and last x,y,z coordinates means that this is no longer a properly ordered surface, so Plotly can't render the graph.

```
fig= go.Figure(data=go.Isosurface(
    x=np.array([1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]),
    y=np.array([0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1]),
    z=np.array([0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]),
    value=theta_2[0].flatten(),
    isomin = 301.3, 
    isomax = 301.6
))
fig.show()
```

[image]

I think you will need to most likely sort one of your arrays (say the x-coordinates), and rearrange the others around that one. I am happy to revisit this problem when I have some more free time, but hopefully this gets you started in the right direction!

Also: anyone with more experience than me in 3D plotting, please chime in!

Comment: I think your initial point is correct and it seems like this is going down the right path, but reordering the points such that one of the arrays is in order does not solve the problem. I even tried to sort the points such that the arrays are in x, y, z order. I wonder if the issue is that these are not rectangular points? I can try that next.

Comment: Oh these are not rectangular points? What kind of coordinate system are you using?

Comment: These are initially geographic polar stereographic points, but even converting (and interpolating) to cartesian coordinates does not work.

Comment: Since the Plotly Isosurface is plotted in 3D cartesian coordinates, I am pretty sure you have to convert the geographic polar stereographic coordinates to cartesian as a first step. After that, you will need to rearrange the points in some way that they form an isosurface— which at the moment neither of us can figure out from your data. From what I have seen, I think you want (x,y) coordinates to be ordered like np.meshgrid orders coordinates

Comment: Agreed on your first point. It seems that it didn't like my coordinates even if they were cartesian, though. Just incidentally, my coordinates *come* from np.meshgrid. I ended up having to give up on this approach and I used mayavi for my 3D plot instead. It certainly doesn't look as nice but it actually works which is nice. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem! I was actually just about to suggest mayavi based on another answer on SO. I think Plotly, like matplotlib, may simply have trouble rendering complicated isosurfaces. Glad you were able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is unable to use the mayavi workaround due to dependency issues (like me), interpolating the data to a regular grid using `np.mgrid` and `scipy.interpolate.griddata` worked for my situation.

In the below example z, lon, and lat are 3d arrays of height, x, and y respectively. The data array is a 3d array of values at (z,lon,lat)

```
# Data coordinates
points = np.array( (z.flatten(), lon.flatten(), lat.flatten()) ).T
# Data values @ above coords
values = data.flatten()

# Grid to interp to
Z, X, Y = np.mgrid[z.min():z.max():20j, lon.min():lon.max():50j, lat.min():lat.max():50j]
# New data values on interp grid
newdata = griddata( points, values, (Z,X,Y) )

fig = go.Figure(data=[
            go.Isosurface(x=X.flatten(),y=Y.flatten(),z=Z.flatten(),
                       value=newdata.flatten(),
                       opacity=0.3,
                       isomin=15,
                       isomax=30,
                       surface_count=5,
                       lighting=dict(ambient=0.7),
                       colorscale='amp',
                       showscale=False,
                       caps=dict(x_show=False, y_show=False)
                       ),
            ])
```

For whatever reason even though my data was already gridded, plotly worked when I re-interpolated everything to a uniform grid. Not very efficient, but it works.